# (Java) Stop movement through walls

Tags: java, collision-detection

I have entity objects that are represented by images for a game I'm creating. I am able to detect simple collisions involving rectangles but I'm not sure how to stop object from moving through each other...

I don't want much of a physics simulation. I just don't want any objects to be able to go through each other. If the entity runs into a wall, it stops. If a wall runs into an entity, the wall stops.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3190/advanced_collision_detection_.php). Specifically the first case might be simple enough for you. Essentially create a bounding box that covers the area an object moves through and check for collisions w/ it

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be to have a list of all your "entities" and check them for collisions.
Make each entity know it's own radius (for circullar collision) or bounding box (for rectangular collision).
Then have a loop like the following:

```
for (int x = entityList.count; i < 0; i--)
{
    for (int y = entityList.count; i < 0; i--)
    {
        if (x == y) continue; // Make sure you don't check to collide with yourself
        CheckIfCollides(entityList[x], entitylist[y]);
    }
}
```

Edit:
You could have the collision code to be ran every time an entity tries to update it's position and check to make sure the new position is valid and doesn't collide with anything.

Comment: I've thought about checking whether the next potential position is possible but this would make it so that if I go at an angle against a wall, the object won't move at all, when it should move in the direction it's allowed to move, kind of like sliding on the wall.

Comment: @Linkxgl You could also check for "on which side of the obstacle you are" and only disable movement in the direction that is towards the obstacle. ie. You first check for the movement in whole, and if you get a collision, you check for what if you only move in X axis and so on.

Another way would be to first move then "fix" the collision by moving back along the normal of the collider's edge.